# android : convert to greyscale with transparency

Tags: android, image, grayscale

I'm trying to convert an image I get from a rest call to a greyscale, however I need to keep the transparency because the image is an overlay on a map. I tried :

```
Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
Paint paint = new Paint();
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
cm.setSaturation(0);
ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
paint.setColorFilter(f);
c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
```

But it doesn't keep the transparency ... so if any of you has an idea I'll be glad to test it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Bitmap.Config is RGB_565 which doesn't have an alpha which is the transparency layer. Try ARGB_8888.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a little bonus, is there a way to fasten the process ?